# Significance of BrE vs AmE in the US

Tags: american-english

I've been working on a thesis concerning the differences between British English and American English. I studied that in the past a standardization of American English was refused, even if spoken and written language were two different things in the United States, and this was because of the opposition of English purists. Today, American newspapers and academic books are written in American English? I mean, for example, they try not to use the past perfect or the present perfect where the British would use it and they prefer the past simple? In the educational system, is standard English that is taught or American English?

Comment: In the US, American English *is* standard English.

Comment: We don't **try** to do anything with the past perfect or the present perfect. We just write using the tenses we are accustomed to using, which means that occasionally there are places where the British would use the present perfect, and we would use the past simple.

Comment: As George Gershwin wrote: "I say "to-may-to" and you say "to-mat-o," etc.

Comment: I know you don't try to do anything, what I'm interested to understand is, at school Americans study Standard English? And what about the teaching of the pronunciation? Thank you

Comment: @Alessandro: We are taught standard American English. This is different from standard British English (for example, *gotten* is not a word in British English). Pronunciation is only discussed when children are learning to read. Since actual American pronunciation differs in some words across the U.S. (*cot/caught* being the most significant difference), it may be that this is taught differently in different areas of the country.

Comment: @Alessandro: I don't believe the spoken and written languages are any more different in the U.S. than in the U.K. Maybe Americans say *gonna* and write *going to,* but I believe there are just as many such contractions in U.K. speech.

Comment: Ok thank you! One last thing, is it usual that a book whose original language is not English, is translated in BrE and AmE?

Comment: @Alessandro: I believe this would only ever happen for children's books. Although since *Harry Potter,* American book publishers have become much more accepting of Britishisms in children's literature.

Comment: Your question assumes wrongly that there is a marked difference between American and British in written records and that whatever differences there are, only one of BrE and AmE is standard. In written English, what is taught in school, the primary difference is spelling: eg BrE 'colour' vs AmE 'color'. Both sides are writing 'standard' English because they are not appreciably different (ie, English isn't like Italian). As to informal speech, there's lots different, especially pronunciation and vocabulary, but it ain't taught in school.

Comment: I've been working on a thesis on the differences between BrE and AmE, in order to limit the area of research I've been working on an Italian book that has been translated in BrE and AmE. I assure you that it's non a difficoult book but it's not for children, in Italy most of the audience is between 20 and 30 years old.

Comment: Disclaimers: Pardon my exclusion of other varieties of English (Irish/Scottish/Australian/etc), and pardon my oversimplification. Also, I'm aware that in studying English as a foreign language, one chooses either the American variety or the British variety, but that is primarily for pronunciation. But to the OPs way of writing his question, assuming that AmE is not the standard and BrE is, that's just not the case at all. The standard they speak in both countries is the same and that is modern standard English (with some minor differences).

Comment: @Alessandra: since you are interested in the differences, yes there are quite a few outstanding ones (many of the questions at ELU are about the differences) but as far as "newspapers and academic books" are concerned there's one standard (again, some vocabulary and spelling and those differences are infrequent and surprising).

Comment: @AlessandroMosca: There is no "Standard English", that is, in America, "Standard English" is "American English" and in the UK "Standard English" is "British English". (and in Canada "Standard English" is Canadian English, etc). Your question is flawed because it assumes some level of importance for British English, but non-British people don't hold the British dialect in such high esteem.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry not to have been clear. The fact is that I'm confused. So Mitch, I've understood well it's correct to speak about the standard American English and Standard British English. If you tell me that for example in written English, what is taught in school, the primary difference is spelling: eg BrE 'colour' vs AmE 'color', why has Mr Peter Shor written that in American schools British words or spelling are incorrect? Thank you for your great patience

Comment: I wanted to say, If I've understood well

Comment: I didn't say that British words (there are very few differences) would be marked incorrect, but that they are not taught. In school, children and teachers would call vehicles "trucks" and not "lorries", but I don't believe somebody using the British word in an essay would be marked down. British spelling would very likely be marked as incorrect. There are relatively few grammar differences, and for nearly all of these, the British grammar is not actually incorrect in America, but just used less often.

Comment: @Alessandro: yes, that's about it, standard written American English and standard written British English (and also that most would be unaware of such a distinction -and- that the distinction is very minor, mostly spelling. As to Peter's statement, yes, if an American writes 'colour', in school or in a newspaper article, it will be marked wrong/changed to 'color' (and exactly the same way but switched in England).

Comment: [The Name of the Rose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Name_of_the_Rose), to pick the most famous modern Italian novel I can think of, appears to have only been translated once (and very well, although I am judging solely from the result, since I don't know Italian). The publishers of the U.K. edition do not even seem to have changed the spelling from American spelling. Presumably in your example, an American and a British publisher  independently commissioned different translations.

Comment: Judging the difference between British and American dialects from a novel seems very chancy to me, since there are undoubtedly many stylistic differences between the two translators' voices which have nothing to do with the way Brits and Americans speak.

Answer (score 1):

When I was a judge at an (American) high school literature contest some years ago, the "standard" was American English. It was with some difficulty that I persuaded my fellow judges NOT to penalize contestants that used "standard" (British) English.

Comment: so, do Americans learn AmE at school and not Standard English? I had a different answer in another forum, where people told me that Americans study English and that the differences are known by American people because they live in the USA, but they aren't thaught

Comment: What sort of American high school would penalize American English? That story sounds completely absurd to me. (Also, it's not really an answer to the question.)

Comment: @onomatomaniak: No, I said the other judges would favor American English and penalize British English. I managed to get the penalty "revoked."

Comment: Do you mean that for example AmE words or spelling are accepted?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Misread that.

Comment: But is your school an exceptions? Are usually students learnt BrE(standard English) or AmE? For example do teachers teach the word pavement or sidewalk?  And what about the pronunciation? Thank you

Comment: @AlessandroMosca: My school was probably "typical" of American schools.

Comment: AmE spelling is taught. British spelling is **incorrect**. I don't know what AmE words are different from British English words (except maybe for the past participles *gotten* and *snuck*, and *gotten* would be correct while *snuck* would be an acceptable alternative). **No American public school would ever teach British English.** (Although they could mention the differences when reading literature written in the U.K.) They would have to deal with a mob of enraged parents.

Comment: @PeterShor Before dealing with enraged parents, they'd have to import a whole lot of teachers.

Comment: AmE words versus BrE words: No, public schools do not make us use words like tarmac and lorry.

Comment: @Alessandro: "Are usually [American] students learnt BrE(standard English) or AmE?". American students learn the American versions of things. But there is no awareness that there is anything else to learn, or that their variety is possibly not acceptable (just as I'm sure most British feel). If anything, rural or regional variety speakers in both countries might feel pressure to use vocabulary and pronunciation of BrE or AmE (where the region lies). But the vast majority write in a common standard English (and where different are just not aware that heir version might not be standard).

Comment: Ok!Many thanks! Now a question of culture. In the past standard BrE was learnt by American students because of the opposition of the English purists. Do you know when AmE started to be thaught in American schools?

Comment: When was BrE learned by American students? Do you have a reference? I could be wrong, but I vaguely remember seeing in some of the answers on EL&U that some expressions were denigrated quite early in American history for being "too British".